# clearing and changing content of div

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

I'm trying to replace the content of comments div with the new comments by loading it again and replacing the old comments. When i change the content of the div, it replaces the first comment only and repeat the whole comment:

here is the comments div :

```
<?php
$comment_qry = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$post_row[id]' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($comment_row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment_qry)){ 
?>
<div id="comments_div">
    <div style="background:#aaaaaa; margin:5px;">
        <p onclick="report_var(<?php echo $post_row['id']; ?>, <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?>);">report</p>
        <p>user: <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?></p>
        <p>date: <?php echo date("Y-m-d", $comment_row['date']); ?></p> 
        <p>content: <?php echo $comment_row['content']; ?></p>
        <?php if($post_row['user_id'] == $my_id or $comment_row['user_id'] == $my_id or $admin == 1){ ?>
             <p><span onclick="comment_remove(<?php echo $comment_row['id']; ?>, <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?>);">delete</span></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

ajax code :

```
/////////////////////////comment function
function comment(post_id, poster_id)
{
loadXMLDoc("php/comment.php?post_id="+post_id+" content="+document.getElementById("content").value+"&poster_id="+poster_id,function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("comments_div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  });
}
```

comment.php :

```
<?php
$comment_qry = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$_GET[post_id]' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($comment_row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment_qry)){ 
?>
    <div style="background:#aaaaaa; margin:5px;" class="comment">
        <p onclick="report_var(<?php echo $post_row['id']; ?>, <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?>);">report</p>
        <p>user: <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?></p>
        <p>date: <?php echo date("Y-m-d", $comment_row['date']); ?></p> 
        <p>content: <?php echo $comment_row['content']; ?></p>
        <?php if($_GET['poster_id'] == $my_id or $comment_row['user_id'] == $my_id or $admin == 1){ ?>
             <p><span onclick="comment_remove(<?php echo $comment_row['id']; ?>, <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?>);">delete</span></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Comment.php code isn't relevant to the question, I don't think. If it's not, just remove it so it's cleaner for the readers

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but `post_id='$_GET[post_id]'` should be `post_id='{$_GET[post_id]}'` and `post_id='$post_row[id]'` should be `post_id='{$post_row[id]}'`

Comment: the problom is in innerHTML its replace the first comment only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code snippet is creating a separate `comments_div` for **each** comment. Then your JavaScript code snippet is just replacing the content of the first one.

You can fix it by putting the `comments_div` *outside* the the PHP `while` loop, and then using the same HTML output code inside that loop as you are in your third example (a `div.comment` per comment).

So, something like this in place of that first code snippet:

```
<div id="comments_div">
<?php
$comment_qry = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$post_row[id]' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($comment_row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment_qry)){ 
?>
    <div style="background:#aaaaaa; margin:5px;" class="comment">
        <p onclick="report_var(<?php echo $post_row['id']; ?>, <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?>);">report</p>
        <p>user: <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?></p>
        <p>date: <?php echo date("Y-m-d", $comment_row['date']); ?></p> 
        <p>content: <?php echo $comment_row['content']; ?></p>
        <?php if($_GET['poster_id'] == $my_id or $comment_row['user_id'] == $my_id or $admin == 1){ ?>
             <p><span onclick="comment_remove(<?php echo $comment_row['id']; ?>, <?php echo $comment_row['user_id']; ?>);">delete</span></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```